# Printing a base 4294967296 integer in base 10

Tags: c++, gmp

I have in C++ a vector of 32 bits integers (variable size, continous memory; like a C-array), representing a number in base 4294967296. I would like to print it in base 10.

These numbers can be extremely big and take over a few megabytes of memory.

What would be the best way to do this in terms of performance? Can I use GMP to do this?

Comment: just pure curiosity..  2^32000000 with integer precision? what do are you doing?

Comment: @yi_H 2^32 to be exact. Basically I want to print a base 2^32 integer in a human-readable form. Humans don't know 2^32 characters, so I only want to use the digits 0..9.

Comment: yes, you repeated your question. you said it's base 2^32 and it takes a couple of megabytes, **so** the numbers are in the order of 2^32000000. with integer *precision*. my question was: what the heck are you doing?

Comment: +1 just for doing something I consider unusual =]

Comment: @yi_H sorry, I misunderstood your comment. My program is an interpreter for a programming language. It has specific goals, including support for giant numbers.

Comment: But humans know base 16(hexadecimal). And conversion from base 2^32 to base 16 is trivial and unlike base 10 it preserves most of the properties of the original representation.

Comment: @WTP: you should use GMP for data representation too, not only for printing...

Comment: What exactly *is* base 2^32? Never heard of it and Google doesn't give any clue.

Comment: @Xeo in base 2^32 you have 2^32 different digits, like in base 10 you have 10 different digits (0 to 9), and in base 2 you have 2 different digits (1 and 0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use GMP for this. The function that you're looking for is `mpn_get_str`:

http://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#Low_002dlevel-Functions

Now the only issue is the size of `mp_limb_t`. It is either a 32-bit integer or a 64-bit integer depending on the platform.

- If it's a 32-bit integer, then you can call the function directly on your array of 32-bit integers. (if the endian matches)
- If it's a 64-bit integer, you may be able to still use it with just a pointer cast. (depending on the alignment and the endianness) Otherwise, you'll have to copy your array into an array of 64-bit integers before you can call `mpn_get_str`.

Alternatively, it might be easier to use the `mpz` integer class. [Import](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export) your integer array into a large integer, then [print](http://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html#Converting-Integers) it back out in base 10.